# About proving that maximal ideals are prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a Ring with unity, and $I$ a maximal ideal in $R$. Show that $I$ is a prime ideal.

I have seen this proof in many places

If $ab\in I$ and $a\notin I$, then $I+(a)=R$ and hence there is some $r\in R$ and $i\in I$ such that $i+ra=1$. Multiplying by $b$,
$$ib+rab=b.$$
$I$ is an ideal and $i\in I$, so that $ib\in I$, and we also have $ab\in I$ by assumption. Therefore, we can conclude that  $ib+rab=b\in I$.

The 1'st question I have is why does $a\notin I$, imply $I+(a)=R$ or more specifically, why does $a\notin I$ imply that $I$ is properly contained in $I+a$?

My 2nd question is, where do we ever use that R is commutative?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since $a \notin I$, $I$ is a proper subset of $I + (a)$; $I + (a)$ is also an ideal in $R$, and since $I$ is maximal, $I + (a)$ must be all of $R$.

Comment: Do you think you should use commutativity?

Comment: Btw, a much nicer proof is: If $R/I$ is a field then it has no zeor divisors.

Comment: $2\mathbb{Z}$ is an Ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\notin \mathbb{2Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$ is not a subset of $3+2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What am I not seeing @T.Bongers ? could you explain why the inclusion is true.

Comment: $2\mathbb Z$ is certainly a subset of $3\mathbb Z+2\mathbb Z$. The definition of the sum of ideal is $I+J=\{a+b:a\in I,b\in J\}$, so both $I$ and $J$ sit inside there by taking $b=0$ or $a=0$, respectively. If you assume that $I=I+(a)$, then in particular $a\in I+(a)$ so $a\in I$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: $I$ is a proper subset of $I+(a)$ because firstly $I+(a)$ contains $I$ by definition; secondly $I+(a)$ contains $a$, whereas $I$ does not.

Comment: @tmpys, note that depending on the notation you are using, $3+2{\Bbb Z}$ may not be the same as $(3)+2{\Bbb Z}$.

Comment: so $I+(a)$ is not the coset? Can someone write the definition of $I+(a)$ vs the coset $I+a$

Comment: $I+a=\{i+a :i\in I\}$ where as $I+(a)=\{i+na : i\in I, n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: wow. I knew it must be something simple I'm not seeing.... thank you to all of you..

Comment: @tmpys: Have you thought of the way which Hagen suggested you in his second comment?

Answer (score 1):

In answer (at least partially) to your second question, maximal ideals are prime in non-commutative rings also (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings) for example).

However, the definition of prime must be changed, since $ab \in P$ does not imply $ba \in P$ for non-commutative rings.

In non-commutative rings we define say that a (left) ideal $P$ is prime if whenever any two ideals $I$ and $J$ have a product contained in $P$ (i.e. $IJ \subseteq P$) then either $I \subset P$ or $J \subset P$.

This is equivalent to the normal definition when $R$ is commutative. There are equivalent definitions that probably mean your proof would only require minimal modification, but this is why the proof doesn't work off the bat in the non-commutative case.

Though it has been answered in the comments, I will add the answer to your first question too, for completeness.
If $a \notin I$ then $I + (a)$ properly contains $I$ since

1. Clearly if $x \in I$ then $x+0 \in I + (a)$, so $I$ is contained
2. Clearly $a = 0 + a \in I + (a)$, but we have already said that $a \notin I$, hence the containment is proper.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comments, there was confusion between ideal sums and cosets. Below I explain how the proof is simply an ideal-theoretic generalization of one classical proof of Euclid's Lemma, which may lend further insight. To clarify the analogy I will use list notation for ideals, so e.g. $\,(I,J,r) = I+J+ rR.\,$ The first line below presents the classical elementwise proof, where the notation $\,(m,n)\,$ can be read as either $\,d = \gcd(m,n),\,$  or as the principal ideal $\,(m,n) = (d)\subseteq \Bbb Z.\,$ The second line gives the analogous proof using ideals, using said list notation for ideal sums.

$\qquad\qquad\,(p,a)=1,\ \ \ p\ \mid\, \ ab\ \ \Rightarrow\, \ p\ \mid\,\, pb,\ \ ab\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ p\, \mid\  \,(pb,ab)\, =\, (p,a)b\, =\, b$

$\qquad\qquad(P,a)=1,\ P\supseteq (ab)\,\Rightarrow\, P\supseteq Pb,(ab)\,\Rightarrow\,P\supseteq(Pb,ab) = (P,a)b = (b)$

Similarly, many ideal-theoretic results are generalizations of well-known results about elements, principal ideals, or gcds. To gain better intuition on such abstractions it is essential to proceed as above, going back-and-forth between the abstract generalizations and the concrete instances. Doing so helps to effectively and efficiently transfer to the abstract generalizations our well-honed intuiton from prior experience with the concrete objects.